# How to load json file from requests in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have a json file which including key/value parameters. The request will send this file to flask.
How can I load this JSON file and get these parameters?

e.g. JSON file : sample.json

```
{number : 123, weather : sunny}
```

My code is:

```
@app.route('/process', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def post_data():
    if request.method == "POST":
        posted_data = json.loads(request.files['data'])
        print(posted_data)

   return ""
```

I used this which cannot get the content of the JSON file.

Answer (score 1):

for example client(or can use postman to mimic this behaviour) sending payload as (it need to be JSON format)

{"number" : 123, "weather" : "sunny"}

in flask, get those values

```
request_json = request.get_json()
print("Request json:", request_json)
number = request_json.get("number")
weather = request_json.get("weather")
```

you can refer to my lib(mainly like a tutes) which integrates with sqlite3 further  : https://bitbucket.org/Radio_fixed/sqliteforkarate/src/master/

Comment: Thanks. But I want to know how to load a json file in Flask, my request would be one json file and multiple txt files. Any suggestions?

Comment: if need is that data should be json attached file along with text files, so this is one example when a client will send a file. <html>
   <body>
      <form action = "http://xxxx/uploader" method = "POST" 
         enctype = "multipart/form-data">
         <input type = "file" name = "file" />
         <p><input type = "text" name = "name" /></p>
         <input type = "submit"/>
      </form>   
   </body>
</html> in flask to intercept the file would be --> f = request.files['file']
            sf=secure_filename(f.filename)